# Android JSONObject How get few JSONObject of one

Tags: android, json

I have JSONObject and I want get 8 object A,B,C...
my json string:

{"Matches":{"A":[{"team1":"Russia","team2":"France","time":"00:00:00","time0_90":"20","score":"0 : 0","stadium":"Maracana","referee":"ref","group":"A"},{"team1":"Portugal","team2":"Honduras","time":"00:00:00","time0_90":"60","score":"0 : 2","stadium":"","referee":"","group":"A"}]},"success":1}{"Matches":{"B":[{"team1":"Brazil","team2":"Spain","time":"00:00:00","time0_90":"3","score":"1 : 0","stadium":"","referee":"","group":"B"}]},"success":1}{"Matches":{"C":[]},"success":0}{"Matches":{"D":[]},"success":0}{"Matches":{"E":[]},"success":0}{"Matches":{"F":[]},"success":0}{"Matches":{"G":[]},"success":0}{"Matches":{"H":[]},"success":0}

```
       JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
       JSONArray jsonMathes = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("matches"); 
   // ????????
```

Comment: Can you post the actual json response you are getting. the snippet you posted has multiple root elements

Comment: jsonResponse = {"success":1,"Matches":{"A":[{"time0_90":"20","time":"00:00:00","referee":"ref","stadium":"Maracana","score":"0 : 0","group":"A","team1":"Russia","team2":"France"},{"time0_90":"60","time":"00:00:00","referee":"","stadium":"","score":"0 : 2","group":"A","team1":"Portugal","team2":"Honduras"}]}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response structure is:

```
JSONObject
key:value
JSONObject (key: "Matches")
    JSONArray (key: "A")
        JSONObject,
            key:value,
            key:value,
            etc...
        JSONObject
```

To get access to `A`, follow the steps below:

1. Create JSONObject from your response:

   ```
   JSONObject jsonResponseObj = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
   ```
2. Get JSONObject for the key "Matches"

   ```
   JSONObject jsonMatches = jsonResponseObj.getJSONObject("Matches");
   ```
3. This object contains a JSONArray for the key "A", so let's get that array:

   ```
   JSONArray jsonArrayA = jsonMatches.optJSONArray("A");
   ```
4. For your response, you have 2 JSONObjects in this array, so first, let's declare and initialize them:

   ```
   //two JSONObjects
   JSONObject[] jsonObjects = new JSONObject[jsonArrayA.length()];

   //go through the array of JSONObjects and fetch them
   for (int i=0; i < jsonObjects.length; i++) {
       jsonObjects[i] = jsonArrayA.getJSONObject(i);
   }
   ```

   - You now have `A` as JSONArray in jsonArrayA
   - `A` contains 2 JSONObjects, and you have them in jsonObjects[0] and josnObjects[1]
   - If you want to get the contents of those jsonObjects, simply fetch it using the keys, eg.:

     ```
     String team1Obj1 = jsonObjects[0].getString("team1");   // will contain 'Russia'
     String team2Obj2 = jsonObjects[1].getString("team2");   // will contain 'Honduras'

     String stadium1 = jsonObjects[0].getString("stadium");  // will contain 'Maracana'
     ```

     etc.